# Windows 10 Pro 64 bit have reccuring DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE

Tags: drivers, windows-10, crash, bsod, power

I have been getting the BSOD crash ever since i first bought it. it has been a month now. It happens everytime im playing a video game and i drop it to go to google or something, then i try to open the game back up. it also crashes when im using adobe premiere.

IS IT GOOD TO ADD, THAT EVERY TIME I LOG INTO MY PC, THE SCREEN FLICKERS TO BLACK BEFORE IT GOES TO THE DESKTOP. ITS NOT A SMOOTH TRANSITION.

Ive tried many things like, a clean install, Reinstalling the drives, using third party software to install my drives... Im not sure what to do anymore.
 Here is a link to my dump files and my OS info, can someone figure out the problem?...                                                                      The Folder is called. Dump  http://1drv.ms/1Hn2EZG

Comment: Try turning off your power management settings in the control panel. Technically, the issue is related to a less-than-compatible driver, and the best fix is to uninstall it, but the incompatibility is likely related to power state features like sleep and automatic powerdown of the component in question.

Comment: So what are you suggesting i do in clearer terms? 
Thank you so much for the reply

Answer (score 0):

According to the dump, the crash is caused by the device `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1901`.

This is the PCIe Controller from the Intel chipset. I see that this controller hosts a device `PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_139B`:

```
    DevNode 0xffffe000663e5d30 for PDO 0xffffe000663e9060
      InstancePath is "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1901&SUBSYS_01521558&REV_07\3&11583659&0&08"
      ServiceName is "pci"
      State = DeviceNodeStarted (0x308)
      Previous State = DeviceNodeEnumerateCompletion (0x30d)
      DevNode 0xffffe00064160d30 for PDO 0xffffe000663626f0
        InstancePath is "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_139B&SUBSYS_01521558&REV_A2\4&bed9ab3&0&0008"
        ServiceName is "nvlddmkm"
        State = DeviceNodeStarted (0x308)
        Previous State = DeviceNodeEnumerateCompletion (0x30d)
```

This is the `NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M`. So disable power saving options for the GPU and update the driver to version `359.00`).

Comment: Thank yo uso much for the reply, so in clearer terms what are u suggesting i do?

Comment: go to device manager and disable power saving for GPU and open the control panel->power saving and disable PCIe power saving.

Comment: I removed power saving from my control panel on the power options, i also set the laptop to never go to sleep.  i also set both my graphics cards to performance.

Although im not sure how to disable power savingn through the device manager as you instructed.

Comment: do you suggest i update to 359? im using 354, that is the version that was on my manufacturers website.

Comment: ok, go to 359. The august version was 354, so I mixed that

Comment: did it help? Or do you still get crashes?